# Window.print() does not work

Tags: javascript, printing, window

Why this does not works? Only loading the page. Not getting printed. Here I take the src of an iframe and open that url in new window.

```
var myDivObj = document.getElementById('resumedocument').src;
var someXml = '<html><title>Resume</title><body onload="window.print();"><iframe style="height: 1000px; width: 1260px;" src="' + myDivObj + '"/></body></html>';
var printwindow = window.open('', '_blank','fullscreen=yes');
printwindow.document.write(someXml);
printwindow.onload = function() {                               
   printwindow.self.focus();
   printwindow.self.print();
};
```

Comment: What have you debugged on it?

Comment: I would *assume* that this, for one, is not defined. `document.getElementById('resumedocument').src`

Comment: `why does this not work` is not a valid reason for posting on SO. Some work needs to be shown.

Comment: The page is loading correctly. If that has issue, then it will not be loaded, right?

Comment: Check your browser's javascript console for errors..

Comment: @ Cole: I have been trying it for more than one day :(

Comment: have you tired printwindow.print()

Comment: What happens if you put the `printwindow.self.print();` line directly after the `document.write()` (instead of in an `onload` handler)? I assume you're wanting to print once the iframe finishes loading, but putting an `onload` on the parent of the iframe won't do that.

Comment: @ Steve: I accept the answer only if I got the working answer. I think that is the correct way :)

Comment: I tried all these. but I always get blank pages on print.

Comment: so why aren't you setting onload of the iframe to run window.print()?

Comment: and i would call printwindow.document.close() when you're done using document.write()

Comment: If `'resumedocument'` is an iframe on the current page and its `src` is from the same domain as the current page then you can extract its html content directly and write it out to the popup window. Then you can call `printwindow.print()` without needing an onload handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = document.getElementById('resumedocument').src;
var printwindow = window.open('', '', 'fullscreen=yes');
printwindow.document.write('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" onload="window.print()" src='+url+'></iframe>');
```

Comment: @ Heera: very thanks. I got the print. But problem. The print popup displays when I close the window.

Comment: Welcome, did you mean print dialog box ?

Comment: Ya. I meant the print dialog box pops up while closing the new window.

Comment: What I need is after loading complete, the print dialogue should automatically pop up above the window instead of while closing.

Comment: Which browser you are using ? I've tested in chrome latest version and here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uQmzb/).

Comment: Yes. U r right. in chrome it is working. It is a cross platform application. Currently  i am using firefox.

Comment: I've googled for you but found nothing, [here](http://forums.devarticles.com/javascript-development-22/close-a-popup-after-print-4768.html).

Comment: Is it possible to create a popup instead of new window.

Comment: It's easily possible using jqprint (jquery plugin), google it, replied from cell, so can't give the url, but will be here soon.

Comment: Hi, I found one here - jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/7. it works for all other links except mine. My link is http://localhost:8080/hiringsteps/docs/Keneth_1340800082258/Keneth_resume_1340800082258.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do it in onload as you are doing your own document.write. The following code works as an example:

```
    var someXml = '<html><body>Stuff</body></html>';
    var printwindow = window.open('', '_blank','fullscreen=yes');
    printwindow.document.write(someXml);
    printwindow.print();
```

I think your problem is the onload would fire during the window.open method when the document has been loaded. At this point of time your document is '', so there is no handler.

To wait for the IFRAME to load you need to move the onload handler there. For example:

```
    var someXml = '<html><body><iframe id=Frame width="800" height="800" src="http://jsfiddle.net" /></body></html>';
    var printwindow = window.open('', '_blank','fullscreen=yes');
    printwindow.document.write(someXml);
    printwindow.document.getElementById('Frame').onload = function () {
        printwindow.self.focus();
        printwindow.print();
    };​
```

Comment: Yes. I tried this. Printing is ok. But always get blank pages

Comment: The `document.write()` is writing an iframe and I think the OP wants to wait for the iframe to load its content before printing. (But an onload on the iframe's parent doesn't wait for the iframe.)

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CRLZ3/) is the one that works on jsfiddle.net - can you post the one that doesn't for comparison? Actually I see you have accepted an answer, so I guess you have got it working now.

Comment: Yes. The same link is given by Sheikh Heera also. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I found one here - jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/7. it works for all other links except mine. My link is http://localhost:8080/hiringsteps/docs/Keneth_1340800082258/Keneth_resume_1340800082258.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
printwindow.onload = function() {                               
    printwindow.self.focus();
    printwindow.self.print();
};
```

With this line:

```
printwindow.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].onload = function () {
    printwindow.self.focus();
    printwindow.print();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try without the self, as in `printwindow.print()`?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you post an answer with code you haven't tested yourself.

Comment: The line `printwindow.self.print();` on its own should work. I think the problem is more about when/if that line gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Note https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print#Notes :

> Starting with Chrome 46.0 this method is blocked inside an `<iframe>` unless its sandbox attribute has the value `allow-modals`.